# how to increase file upload size in wordpress google compute engine

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

I am new to thw world of VMs and cant figure out out how to increase the max file upload size of a wordpress vm in compute engine.

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with WordPress theme's `functions.php`

```
ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

or with `php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

or with `.htaccess`

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

make sure the instance has enough resources assigned.

Comment: My problem is that i have configured WinSCP with my instance but can't see any files through it and am unable to navigate through or modify the wordpress files and so am looking for instructions to do the same. Sorry for not clarifying this earlier!

Comment: @user1447156 what's the point in having a client, which is unable to browse the file-system? your SSHd might not be configured properly... while this is completely out of scope; question answered.

Comment: zeitlar as I said I am new to com's and can't see any files in my directory of the vm